# c# wrapper for native library

Tags: c#, c++, dll, freeglut

I'm working on making a c# wrapper for freeglut and it was going smoothly until I hit an issue.

nativeGL.cpp:

```
extern "C"
{
    FREEGLUTNATIVE_API void GL_DRAW_POLY(Vector2 *points, int count)
    {
        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        glColor3b(0,255,255);
        std::cout << count << " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            //std::cout << points[i].x << " " << points[i].y << "    ";
            glVertex3d(points[i].x, points[i].y, 0);
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

GL.cs:

```
public static class GL
{

    [DllImport(dllName: "FREEGLUTNATIVE.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void GL_DRAW_POLY(Vector2[] points, int count);

    public static void DrawPolygon(Vector2[] points) {
        GL_DRAW_POLY(points, points.Length);
    }
}
```

Other methods work such as GL.CreateWindow and that works but for some reason GL.DrawPolygon doesn't work. the `cout`ing works and give the expected output, but nothing is appearing on the window.

PS.
This is a learning experience

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd99e6zt.aspx

Comment: its not the array that's messing up. if I uncomment the `std::cout << points[i].x << " " << points[i].y << "    ";` I would get the expected result printed